# how recognize Html Link (anchor) in page_load after click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, anchor

i have some anchors in my aspx page.
i need to determine them (couse to run page_load) in page_load after click.
as you know those anchors are not regular asp.net controls and when you click them `Page.IsPostBack` is always false.
i can not use linkbuttons for some reasons.
so, how can i determine those anchors in page_load after click?

thanks in advance

Comment: check query string or Page.RawUrl, you should catch the #anchorName in there, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my only idea is tu use parameters in url and use them to identify which hyperlink was clicked.

```
<a href="page.aspx?linkName=link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="page.aspx?linkName=link2">Link 2</a>
```

And in code behind

```
string linkName = Request.QueryString["linkName"];
if (linkName = "link1")
{ // something
}
```

But what's the reason you cannot use `LinkButtons` or some other controls? This approach would be more convenient in ASP.NET.

Comment: +1, another trick would be to use `<a href="?linkName=link1">foo</a>`, and the browser adds it to the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way would be to use __doPostBack function(It's already there in every asp.net page) in javascript and set appropiate 
event targent and event argument. This is how asp.net controls posts back to server

for example.

```
<a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Anchor1','')">LinkButton</a>
```

On the server Side, you could handle the click event as following

```
protected void Anchor1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World !");
}
```

Comment: Well, you're right, however personally I don't like creating such solutions, those don't seem to obvious and readable for me. Not saying that my solution is better - just more readable. Best approach would be to simply not use anchors and stick to Asp.Net controls.

Comment: Well the whole ASP.Net works in the above way. Many things are abstracted from the developer(Not that developer should not know it). Porting windows form based programming to web required Microsoft to introduce these kinds of hacks(__doPostBack, ViewState). For clean and readable-web-based programming MVC is the way to go